# Performance issue with geb lookup on module object attributes vs. using selectors

Tags: performance, groovy, spock, geb

### Problem Description

I am writing a geb/spock spec which fetches test data from DB2 into a map (the map variable is called "*preFilledFields*" - see the "*MySpec*" class further down).

This map is then being iterated over, and for each iteration I check too see if the value matches one in a row on the page.

When I perform the assertion above accessing the module object attributes, then the average execution time per assertion is approx. 5-6 seconds. If I perform the assertion using selectors directly, then the average execution time per assertion is approx. 70-80 ms. See the "*MyPage*" class for more details regarding the assertions.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this? Is the bad performance a result of my code, or is there a general problem with regards to performance when using modules in geb?

Appreciate any help and input I can get.

### Code:

My "RowModule" class looks like this:

```
class RowModule extends Module {

static final PREDEFINED_ATTR = "data-predefined-amount"

static content = {
    cell { $("td", it) }
    description { cell(0).text() }
    rubrikNum { cell(1).text().toInteger() }
    preDefinedAmount { cell(0).parent("tr").$("td[$PREDEFINED_ATTR]").attr("$PREDEFINED_ATTR") }
    inputField { cell(0).parent("tr").$("td input") ?: false }
    dataType{ cell(0).parent("tr").attr("data-type") }
}
```

}

My Page class looks like this:

```
class MyPage extends Page {
    static url = "<some_url>"
    static at = { $("h1").text() == "<some_text>" }

    static content = {
        submitButton { $("input", name:"<some_name>") }
        myPageItems {
            $("table tr").collect { it.module(RowModule) }
        }
    }

    void verifyPrePopulatedFields(name, amount) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();            
        assert amount == selvangivelseItems.find { it.dataType== name}.preDefinedAmount.toInteger()
        //assert amount == $("tr[data-type='" + name+ "']").$(".skts-tooltip-holder").text().toInteger()
        println "Execution time" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now) + " ms"
    }

    void submit() { submitTaxReturnButton.click() }
}
```

My Spec file looks like this:

```
class MySpec extends GebReportingSpec {
    @Unroll
    def "field #name is pre-populated with amount #amount from the database"() {
        expect:
            page(MyPage) verifyPrePopulatedFields(name, amount)
        where:
            name <<  preFilledFields.keySet()
            amount <<  preFilledFields.values()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no general performance problems with using modules in Geb, at least none that I know of. Your selectors on the other hand are definitely suboptimal.

Firstly by doing `myPageItems.find { it.dataType == name }` you are iterating over all rows in your table and executing 3 WebDriver commands (that is http request between your test and the browser that is being driven) for each of them. You could improve the selector for `dataType` to `dataType { attr("data-type") }` (not 100% sure here because I don't see your DOM structure but this is what logic would suggest) but it would still mean potentially making a lot of requests. You should instead add a site content definition like this:

```
myItem { dataType ->
     $("table tr[data-type='$dataType']").module(RowModule)
}
```

And then use it like:

```
assert amount == myPageItem(name).preDefinedAmount.toInteger()
```

Secondly you can simplify and improve performance of your selectors in the module (if my assumptions about your DOM are correct):

```
static content = {
    cell { $("td", it) }
    description { cell(0).text() }
    rubrikNum { cell(1).text().toInteger() }
    preDefinedAmount { $("td[$PREDEFINED_ATTR]").attr("$PREDEFINED_ATTR") }
    inputField { $("td input") ?: false }
    dataType{ attr("data-type") }
}
```

You should avoid using multiple selectors for things that can be found using a single selector or using unnecessary selectors because they will always carry a performance penalty.